Why is the tooltip not visible in the Yandex browser?
I use taigaUI library for create beauty disabled button and tooltip. This tooltip displays in chrome and other popular browsers. However yandex-browser isnt displays tooltip.
Here is a live example:
Please help me make visible tooltip for this disabled button in yandex-browser.
It's important that I use exactly a disabled button.
code:
<tui-root>
  <button
    tuiIconButton
    type="button"
    icon="tuiIconFileText"
    [tuiHint]="hint"
    tuiHintAppearance="onDark"
    tuiHintDirection="bottom"
    [disabled]="true"
  >
    Button
  </button>

  <ng-template #hint>
    <div>this is a hint</div>
  </ng-template>
</tui-root>

